# How do i fixed containers in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment, containers, row

I want to make first container fixed in center and second container fixed in right but i couldn't. I add mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween in row line but it didn't work. Is there different properties to adjust position of widgets?

My Code:

```
new Container(
  width: 360,
  height: 502,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [
        Color(0xffffffff),
        Color(0x00caebfe) 
      ],
      stops: [0,1]
    )
  ),
  child:Column(
    //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children:<Widget>[
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text("JULY 2017",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Baloo',
                color: Color(0xff181743),
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
              )
            )
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            //padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:90.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                width: 14,
                height: 5,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      Color(0xfffe1e9a),
                      Color(0xfffea64c) 
                    ],
                    stops: [0,1]
                  ),
                )
              ),
              new Container(
                //margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:3.0),
                width: 23,
                height: 5,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      Color(0xfffe1e9a),
                      Color(0xfffea64c) 
                    ],
                    stops: [0,1]
                  )
                )
              )
          ],)
          )
        ]
      )
    ]
  )
),
```

Is there different properties to adjust position of widgets?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what's currently displayed when you run this?

Comment: use Stack instead of Row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following what you said you wanted to achieve, as in having the text centred and the gradients all the way to the right, I've modified your code by adding an `Expanded` widget around the first `Container` in `Row` and removing the width of your top `Container`:

```
Container(
  height: 502,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [
        Color(0xffffffff),
        Color(0x00caebfe)
      ],
      stops: [0,1]
    )
  ),
  child: Column(
    children:<Widget>[
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Text("JULY 2017",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Baloo',
                  color: Color(0xff181743),
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                )
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                width: 14,
                height: 5,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      Color(0xfffe1e9a),
                      Color(0xfffea64c)
                    ],
                    stops: [0,1]
                  ),
                )
              ),
              new Container(
                //margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:3.0),
                width: 23,
                height: 5,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      Color(0xfffe1e9a),
                      Color(0xfffea64c)
                    ],
                    stops: [0,1]
                  )
                )
              )
            ],)
        ]
      )
    ]
  )
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make your `FirstContainer` placed at the very center, and your `SecondContainer` at the very end?

If so, you might want to use `Row`, and `Expanded`

So it would be something like this:

```
Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: [
        /// Just a placeholder container to occupy 1/3 of the Row
        Expanded(child: Container()),
        Expanded(child: FirstContainer()),
        Expanded(child: SecondContainer()),
    ]
)
```

What this does, is add a placeholder container which occupies 1/3 of the Row, and your `FirstContainer` will be forced to be at the center, and `SecondContainer` section of the Row.

Comment: If you're trying to position the widgets on top of each other, you might want to use the Stack widget.

Comment: I tried this but firstcontainer and secondcontainer are side by side. i want that second container is far right

Comment: Oh, you mean having it overflow? Like the second container going slightly outside of your first container? In that case you might want to use Stack

Answer (score 1):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: new Container(
              width: 360,
              height: 502,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [Color(0xffffffff), Color(0x00caebfe)],
                      stops: [0, 1])),
              child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned(
                      right: 0,
                      child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text("JULY 2017",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Baloo',
                                color: Color(0xff181743),
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                              ))),
                    ),
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                            child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Container(
                                width: 14,
                                height: 5,
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                                      Color(0xfffe1e9a),
                                      Color(0xfffea64c)
                                    ], stops: [
                                      0,
                                      1
                                    ]))),
                            new Container(
                                //margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:3.0),
                                width: 23,
                                height: 5,
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                                      Color(0xfffe1e9a),
                                      Color(0xfffea64c)
                                    ], stops: [
                                      0,
                                      1
                                    ])))
                          ],
                        ))),
                  ])),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Check out this method using stack it makes it simple later can later modify thank-you.

Comment: This answer is also quite valid, as it's a slightly different interpretation of what the poster asked. Why has it been downvoted? This is suspicious.

Comment: this answer valid but ugly, because a lot of redundant widgets